# How to fix C# Jagged arrays Type Conversion Error

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

This is from C# data structure and algorithm course by MS on edx.

"Jagged arrays
A jagged array is simply an array of arrays, and the size of each array can vary."

```
int[][] jaggedArray = new int[10][];

jaggedArray[0] = new Type[5];//cannot implicitly convert type 'system.Type[]' to 'int[]'

jaggedArray[1] = new Type[7];//cannot implicitly convert type 'system.Type[]' to 'int[]'

jaggedArray[9] = new Type[21];//cannot implicitly convert type 'system.Type[]' to 'int[]'
```

expected result: no error

actual result: cannot implicitly convert type 'system.Type[]' to 'int[]'

Please help.

Update:
I am new to C#, and I think there is error in the course: https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:Microsoft+DEV204.3x+1T2019/courseware/3544566571fe4074b46541d73149ad8d/c97ee813019947a0b2ba0dfb1f60b132/1?activate_block_id=block-v1%3AMicrosoft%2BDEV204.3x%2B1T2019%2Btype%40vertical%2Bblock%4008d10138ab7542969703766ee6eb1b03

I will report to the course.

Thanks for the comment and answer. They help.

Comment: You should declare jagged array elements with same type, e.g. `jaggedArray[0] = new int[5]`. Remember that `System.Type` != `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment says, System.Type is not the same as int, I think you want something like:

```
Type[][] jaggedArray = new Type[10][];
jaggedArray[0] = new Type[5];
jaggedArray[1] = new Type[7];
jaggedArray[9] = new Type[21];
```